# Making sure if value of variable changes or not

Tags: llvm

Is there a way to ascertain that a particular SSA variable value does not change between 2 points in the program?

Answer (score 6):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single_assignment_form):

> In compiler design, static single assignment form (often abbreviated
>   as SSA form or simply SSA) is a property of an intermediate
>   representation (IR), which says that each variable is assigned exactly
>   once.

So I'm not sure if your question has any meaning.

In the fashion of GEB, I'd answer "mu" ;-)